# openlayers, drawing clouds, polygon with customized stroke

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am working with openlayers 6 and I need to draw clouds on the maps a polygon with half circles stroke or a linestring, it doesn't matter the type as long as I can modify it ( adding and removing  points,  stretching, shrinking it). My knowledge of Openlayers is very limited so I am asking for guidance, how can I possibly do that

[image: this image containes and example of what I want to achieve, an editable cloud shape drawn by a user]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom style which changes the displayed geometry, similar to https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/polygon-styles.html but replacing the segments of the polygon ring with semi-circular arcs.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.14.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      html, body, .map {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.14.1/build/ol.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script>
      var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      });

      var source = new ol.source.Vector({wrapX: false});

      var style = new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: 'blue',
          width: 3
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)'
        }),
        geometry: function (feature) {
          var geometry = feature.getGeometry();
          if (geometry.getType() === 'Polygon') {
            var coordinates = geometry.getCoordinates(true)[0];
            var arcs = [];
            for (let i = 0, len = coordinates.length - 1; i < len; ++i) {
              var center = [
                (coordinates[i + 1][0] + coordinates[i][0]) / 2,
                (coordinates[i + 1][1] + coordinates[i][1]) / 2
              ];
              var dx = coordinates[i + 1][0] - coordinates[i][0];
              var dy = coordinates[i + 1][1] - coordinates[i][1];
              var radius = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) / 2;
              var angle = Math.atan2(-dy, -dx);
              var sides = 32;
              arcs = arcs.concat(
                ol.geom.Polygon.fromCircle(
                  new ol.geom.Circle(center, radius),
                  sides,
                  angle
                ).getCoordinates(true)[0].slice(0, sides / 2)
              );
            }
            return new ol.geom.Polygon([arcs.concat([arcs[0]])]);
          } else {
            return geometry;
          }
        }
      });

      var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: source,
        style: style
      });

      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [raster, vector],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [-11000000, 4600000],
          zoom: 4
        })
      });

      var modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({source: source});
      map.addInteraction(modify);

      var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
        source: source,
        type: 'Polygon',
        style: style
      });
      map.addInteraction(draw);

      var snap = new ol.interaction.Snap({source: source});
      map.addInteraction(snap);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Second example with elliptical arcs:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.14.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      html, body, .map {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.14.1/build/ol.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script>
      var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      });

      var source = new ol.source.Vector({wrapX: false});

      var style = new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: 'blue',
          width: 3
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)'
        }),
        geometry: function (feature) {
          var geometry = feature.getGeometry();
          if (geometry.getType() === 'Polygon') {
            var coordinates = geometry.getCoordinates(true)[0];
            var arcs = [];
            for (let i = 0, len = coordinates.length - 1; i < len; ++i) {
              var center = [
                (coordinates[i + 1][0] + coordinates[i][0]) / 2,
                (coordinates[i + 1][1] + coordinates[i][1]) / 2
              ];
              var dx = coordinates[i + 1][0] - coordinates[i][0];
              var dy = coordinates[i + 1][1] - coordinates[i][1];
              var radius = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) / 2;
              var angle = Math.atan2(-dy, -dx);
              var sides = 32;
              var circle = ol.geom.Polygon.fromCircle(
                new ol.geom.Circle(center, radius),
                sides,
                angle
              );
              circle.rotate(-angle, center);
              circle.scale(1, 0.5, center);
              circle.rotate(angle, center);
              arcs = arcs.concat(
                circle.getCoordinates(true)[0].slice(0, sides / 2)
              );
            }
            return new ol.geom.Polygon([arcs.concat([arcs[0]])]);
          } else {
            return geometry;
          }
        }
      });

      var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: source,
        style: style
      });

      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [raster, vector],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [-11000000, 4600000],
          zoom: 4
        })
      });

      var modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({source: source});
      map.addInteraction(modify);

      var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
        source: source,
        type: 'Polygon',
        style: style
      });
      map.addInteraction(draw);

      var snap = new ol.interaction.Snap({source: source});
      map.addInteraction(snap);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for you time and your answer and I apologize if my questions aren't professionel, i am just begining with openlayers,,
according to your asnwer it does the job , but isn't really user friendly , if you can show me how to do it as Drawing a LineString or Polygon instead starting with Circle

Comment: The Draw interaction produces both a polygon and a LineString for the already drawn segments, so I have updated the answer to allowed both to be styled.  Instead of a single style with geometry function you could also use a style function, with would allow different color, width, etc., for the LineString and polygon.

Comment: Still the same issue which is starting with a circle and I want it to be like drawing a regular Polygon or LineString just with customized Stroke. Arcs with similaire radius between all the Polygon points, for ex: assuming the max radius is 100 and the distrance between point A and B is 1050 the result is instead having a straight line between A and B i want to have 6 arcs  5 arcs with r= 100  and one with r=25. And also the aibility to modify

Comment: It is possible to modify in the example - if adding vertices the interaction acts on the drawn geometry polygon, not the displayed cloud.  You might want to disable further drawing before modifying.  If you require more complex arcs such as ellipses you could calculate your own or scale a circular arc. I have added a second example which uses a fixed scale, but you could determine the the appropriate scale to for each segment.

Comment: if you take a look at this example https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/style/map.style.hashlines.html , I want same fonctionnalites the difference is  arcs between point  instead of line hashs  and no main line

Comment: The final result is the aibilty of  the user to draw "TEMSI" graphs  like shown here https://www.lavionnaire.fr/CodesTemsi.php